# Could not start Tern server in Emacs

Tags: node.js, emacs, tern

I have the latest version of Emacs and [Tern](http://ternjs.net/doc/manual.html) but I have a problem with using the plugin. When I use any Tern-related commands I get this command from editor:

```
Wrong type argument: listp, "Could not start Tern server
env: node: No such file or directory.
"
```

As far as I know, Tern uses NodeJs to do it's job, I have the latest version of NodeJs also but I don't know why I get this error.

Comment: Is "node" executable on the path?  Emacs seems to be complaining about that.

Comment: @juanleon I can run `node` command in bash.

Comment: Did you solve this? I had a similar issue some time ago, I solved by launching emacs from the command line.

Comment: @AlbertoZaccagni No I didn't! How?

Comment: Open the shell and run `nohup emacs &`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add the following line to your init file, replacing the path for node if necessary depending on where node is installed:

```
(setenv "PATH" (concat "/usr/local/bin:" (getenv "PATH")))
```

Comment: You can find the path for node via `which node` at the command line.

Answer (score 1):

I used to have the same problem and just make it work. The thing is that the plugin have [hard coded tern-command path](https://github.com/marijnh/tern/blob/master/emacs/tern.el#L86). So I modify the path to "/usr/local/bin/tern".

And because I install the plugin with emacs 24's package, I have to delete `tern.elc` in the plugin folder and recompile it by `C-u 0 M-x byte-recompile-directory`.